# ¿Se puede escribir un caracter de forma automática al hacer click sobre un input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Estoy realizando una aplicación, en la que tengo un pequeño problema con el DatePicker, y para solucionarlo necesito escribir un número de forma automática al hacer click sobre dicho input.

Os expongo las imágenes y el código empleado:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha").on("click", function () {
    
    var fechaCalendario;
    fechaCalendario = $(".datepicker-switch")[0].firstChild.data
     var anioActual;
    var anioActualStr;
    anioActual = new Date().getFullYear();
    anioActualStr = (anioActual).toString();
    
    
    if (fechaCalendario != undefined && fechaCalendario.indexOf(anioActualStr) ==-1) {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha").val("");
        var barrera = true;
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_fecha").on('focus', function (e) {
            if ($(this).val().length == 1 && barrera) {
                $(this).val(2);
                barrera = false;
            }
        });
        
    }
```

El datepicker siempre aparece con año y mes incorrectos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este problema se soluciona escribiendo un valor cualquiera del teclado e inmediatamente aparece todo correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible escribir algo de forma automática con un evento?

He estado intentando ver el fallo del DatePicker, y todo parece correcto. Al menos, no he conseguido encontrar nada.

Gracias